# which procedural block executed first, in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog, procedural

If I have both *alwas_comb* and *always_ff* in a single module, which one executed first?.

for example, I have seen this code in a book but I am confused about the functionality. for example, if *WE=0* what will be the value of *Qout*?

```
module SyncRAM #(parameter M = 4, N = 8)(output logic [N-1:0] Qout,
   input logic [M-1:0] Address, input logic [N-1:0] Data, input logic clk, WE);

logic [N-1:0] mem [0:(1<<M)-1];

always_comb
  Qout = mem[Address];

always_ff @(posedge clk)
  if (~WE)
    mem[Address] <= Data;

endmodule
```

Any help about the truth table of this code is appreciated,
regards

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer to your question is that `Qout` will just track the value of `mem[Address]`. In other words, on the rising edge of the clock, if `WE` is 0, `Qout` will be driven with the value written to the memory. This is because the memory will behave like a bank of flip-flops, while the `Qout` output will behave as if it is directly connected to the Q output of a bank of flip-flops.

The order of the execution of the two `always` blocks is deterministic, because `Qout` is driven using a *blocking assignment* (`=`), whereas the memory is written to using a *non-blocking assignment* (`<=`). See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169383/what-does-operator-do-in-this-code/37172185#37172185) for much more detail.

Comment: thank you for your answer
if I understand correctly,   when WE=0, Qout keep then previous value and mem[Address] will be updated. Then in the next clock cycle the updated mem[Address] will be assigned to the Qout for either WE=0 or WE=1..
Is that right

Comment: @user42037 I'm sorry. I was talking complete nonsense. (It must have been too early in the morning.) I have edited my answer.